# Invalid API Key from Crashlytics

Tags: android, crash-reports, crashlytics, error-logging

Updated to Android Studio 1.4 Preview and the new SDK and now I get a:

```
ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null.
```

I already uninstalled Fabric, Installed it again, and updated Crashlytics from it

Any ideeas what I should do?

This is my build.gradle: http://pastebin.com/VPHpRJte

This is my androidManifest: http://pastebin.com/Nmdeasx8

My API KEY in Manifest:

```
android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" 
android:value="c13e89xxxxxxxxxxxxx1054b4a
```

In https://fabric.io/settings/organizations/ :

```
c13e89xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbf1054b4a
```

Comment: I don't use Crashlytics.. But I know every Crash reporting API always requires a key provided by the host and you must declare it in your app as instructed by the host.. In your case, I believe you did not set a key

Comment: edited my response to include it

Comment: have u checked your API Secret used to validate your application? it will be inside Crashlytics.properties file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Added the apiKEY inside the crashlytics.properties file like this:

```
#Contains API Secret used to validate your application. Commit to internal source control; avoid making secret public.
#Wed Jul 16 14:41:00 CEST 2014
apiKey=c13e89c059cxxxxxxxxx32f2d48xxxxxxxa
apiSecret=32192cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxecf917b5xxxxxx1
```

Comment: isnt the apiSecret supposed to be a secret?

Comment: @rosu alin, i cannot find  crashlytics.properties in root of my project.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same exception, but I had the key/secret set in the right places.

What happened was I upgraded Android Studio from 1.5 to 2.2, and I started getting this error.

The only way I could get rid of the error was to delete the whole project and git clone it again.  After doing this, the project compiled fine.